# How to add a command in right click menu of a function or class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, plugin.xml

This is kind of newbie question. All tutorials show a way to add a command to a `iFile` object class. Can you show me an example of a `plugin.xml` file that registers a command for a function or class?

What I want to achieve is to right-click on a class or a function name in Outline view or in the code itself and have my new command in the context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use **visibleWhen** part properly. This is an example of a command showing in Project Explorer which is visible only when a Java method or class is selected:

```
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu">
     <command
           commandId="__your.command.id__"
           id="your.contribution.id"
           label="Some Label"
           style="push">
        <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="false">
           <iterate
                 ifEmpty="false"
                 operator="and">
              <or>
                 <instanceof
                       value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType">
                 </instanceof>
                 <instanceof
                       value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IMethod">
                 </instanceof>
              </or>
           </iterate>
        </visibleWhen>
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

Don't forget to set commandId to something real.

You can find more info about property and selection testing [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions).

Comment: This shows the label only in the ProjectExplorer. How to make it visible in any context (e.g. in source editor)?

Comment: Use **popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any** for locationURI. This makes it visible in each part supporting menu contributions, like Project Explorer, Package Explorer, Outline View, Type Hierarchy, Members etc. As for editor it uses different mechanism to provide context menu actions (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/IFile_objectContribution) you need to change `objectClass` to IMethod for method or IType for class.

P.S:

In order to see what kind of object is represented you can use the Plugin SelectionSpy Menu. Select an object and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.